# Create new category in elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have included the following code in the file functions.php in my active theme:

```
function add_elementor_widget_categories( $elements_manager ) {

    $elements_manager->add_category(
        'first-category',
        [
            'title' => esc_html__( 'First Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'icon' => 'fa fa-plug',
        ]
    );
    $elements_manager->add_category(
        'second-category',
        [
            'title' => esc_html__( 'Second Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'icon' => 'fa fa-plug',
        ]
    );

}
add_action( 'elementor/elements/categories_registered', 'add_elementor_widget_categories' );
```

After this step, unfortunately, the category is not added to Elementor.

Comment: If you [read the documentation](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/widgets/widget-categories/) where you got that code from, your categories won't show _until_ you assign widgets to your custom category: _Categories are only displayed in the widgets panel if they have widgets assigned to them._